# Crashlytics doesn't report specific fatal crash on Android

Tags: android, libgdx, crashlytics

I have an Android game, made with LibGDX. One of my users, with device Oneplus 5T, experiences the following problem:
when he switches off the phone screen, while playing the game, and then switches it back on, the game freezes and shortly after closes. This happens to him only when playing my game. And I don't get any crash reports from Crashlytics.

I've tried to surround with try-catch the code in MainActivity.onPause()/onResume() methods, sending non-fatal crash report with Crashlytics, but I didn't get those too.

How do I deal with this? The user is willing to help, he has a root access, and can send any logs I need. The question is, what logs should I collect, and when, and how to write them into a file on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in the `developer options` -> "Bug report shortcut". It shows a button in the power menu for taking a bug report. Tell him to use that when this happens and send the bug report to you.
I have faced a similar issue, when the app was crashing, but I didn't receive that in crashlytics. It turned out that the problematic code was surrounded in a try/catch block. The `try` couldn't execute and the `catch` wasn't handling the error properly. Check your app for such blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about crash reporting, I'll do that.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any exception stacktrace of the original bug. And I've added code to generate another exception, and its stacktrace was in the bug report, and Crashlytics reported it too. Have no idea what to do next.